# Unity Transparent Panel Not displaying gameObject underneath

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have a canvas with a background image and a transparent panel. The canvas has been set to Screen Space - Camera. I have a gameObject that is between the background image and the transparent panel. The gameObject displays above the background image fine however adding the panel element over the gameObject blocks it from view. When I change the transparency of the panel it completely ignores the gameObject and shows the background canvas element below it. Any ideas how I can get the gameObject to display behind the transparent UI panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this is a slightly hacky way. As it would appear you cant sandwich a game object between 2 canvas elements I made my background image a game object and let the canvas always be on top

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to order Renderer in between 2 UI Images(RawImages)?